# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\WSO2\Identity

Tags: java, installation, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have an issue with installing WSO2 locally.
I already follow the steps in the installation guide and when I try to run the server I got the following error.

```
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.17
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\6.1.0
Error: Could not find or load main class Files\WSO2\Identity
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Files\WSO2\Identity
```

JDK v11.017
WsO2 IS v6.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your error, I think you are on a Windows PC, and you have downloaded the installation **installer.msi** option to install the product. Try the binary release, where you get a **.zip** file and extract it to any location, and them you can run from the command prompt.

Also, a common issue when you run WSO2 products initially is the JAVA_HOME. Please check whether you have set the JAVA_HOME correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting this issue since you have Ffolder with spaces in the WSO2 Installation Path. For example `C:\Program Files\WSO2\Identity Server\6.1.0` has two folders with spaces. WSO2 applications don't handle spaces in paths well on Windows, hence move your WSO2 and Java installation to a place where each directory doesn't have any spaces.